# Is it fair for us to conclude XOR string encryption is less secure than well known encryption (Say Blowfish)

Tags: c++, encryption

I was wondering, is it fair to conclude, XOR string encryption is less secure than other encryption method, say [Blowfish](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/blowfish.aspx)

This is because for both methods, their input are

1. Unencrypted string
2. A secret key

---

```
string XOR(string value,string key)
{
    string retval(value);

    short unsigned int klen=key.length();
    short unsigned int vlen=value.length();
    short unsigned int k=0;
    short unsigned int v=0;

    for(v;v<vlen;v++)
    {
        retval[v]=value[v]^key[k];
        k=(++k<klen?k:0);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

---

Is there any proof that XOR encryption method is more easy to be "broken" than [Blowfish](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/blowfish.aspx) if the same key is being chosen?

Comment: Go read chapter 1 of Schneier's _Applied Cryptography_ which discusses specifically why XOR is completely worthless for encryption.

Comment: Here's an excerpt: http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=1685580&postcount=10

Comment: XOR is a stream cipher. Stream cipher are one of the weakest cipher but that does not mean anything in reality its still hard to break if you follow the rules (unfortunately people don't and thus this leads to easily breakable codes). But you have to ask yourself who are you encrypting against. If it is against copy protection from the *average* user then you should be fine. If you are protecting from industrial espionage or the government then nothing bu the strongest ciphers are going to protect you. The most important part of cryptography is know your enemy.

Comment: PS. Yes blowfish is more secure than XOR as it is a block cipher. Look up the difference between Block and stream ciphers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your key is *(a)* truly random, *(b)* at least as long as the plaintext, and *(c)* never re-used then XOR encryption is [proveably unbreakable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

If you can't meet those stringent criteria then XOR encryption is proveably weaker than proper encryption algorithms like Blowfish, though I'm not in a position to prove it myself.

Comment: Just to add: in case you're wondering, truly random means "from a random source" like measuring the decay of a radioactive isotope or such, not a pseudo-random number generator like a `random()` funtion.

Comment: @ninefingers : Why random() can't qualify itself here ?

Comment: @YeenFei To be provably secure, the cryptographically secure PRNG must also be secure; only truly random processes are. Your average C library random function most definitely isn't.

Comment: If you replace the random key with a pseudoradnom key stream then you get a stream cipher. So according to this answer all stream ciphers would be provably less secure than block ciphers. Please don't make such statements when you don't have a reference.

Comment: @Ninefingers: There are a few experts that disagree with you, see http://kerneltrap.org/node/6630 for instance.

Comment: @Accipitridae: Could you elaborate please? Where, and how, am I suggesting that all stream ciphers are proveably less secure than block ciphers?

Answer (score 5):

XOR encryption is wildly unsafe if you try encoding the same string more than once with it because it allows malicious users to recover the XOR of two messages by XORing their encryption.  If they can somehow trick you into XORing a known string, then they can recover your key and break the encryption entirely.

More advanced encryption algorithms like Blowfish and AES have much stronger security guarantees and are assumed to be so strong that even if the attacker lets you encrypt known data, they can't recover your key or recover any individual bits.  They should always be used instead of your own custom encryption in any scenario where security is important.

As an interesting aside, XOR encryption where on each invocation you use a new (randomly-chosen) key is cryptographically unbreakable from an information-theoretic perspective.  This is called a "one-time pad" and could in theory be useful in some settings.

Comment: But, if I know the key for a blowfish encrypted string, I can decrypt the encrypted string using the well known blowfish decrypted method in no time.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that if you don't know the key but still know what the encryption of some data is with that key, you can't recover the key.

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: The *key* is always the secret. If someone has the key he can decrypt the cipher text. In any encryption scheme. That is the point.

Comment: @templatetypedef Can you provide a real working example on how you discover key from an XOR encrypted string?

Comment: @etarion - thanks for the info! now i know why xor is prone to attack since encryption/decryption are using same function (http://pastebin.com/DeR4Yaca). but, if i use arithmetic add/substract, since they are 2 functions, will they suffer from this kind of attack?

Comment: In short, if you use add/subtract, you can be brute forced easily.

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: The insecurity of the XOR cipher when reusing keys doesn't have anything to do with encryption/decryption using the same function. The problem is that if you guess some part of the plaintext (which is often not as hard as it sounds and propbability analysis helps), you directly get the corresponding part of the key (where it's hard to guess the key used to transform a known plaintext into a known cyphertext for blowfish), which in turn lets you decrypt other parts of the message/messages, from which you can most likely derive new parts of the key.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, "XOR encryption" is proven to be perfectly secure against eavesdropping (you are still in trouble when someone can change your stream), given an encryption key that is

- as long as the string to be encrypted
- perfectly random (bits are uncorrelated and have equal probabilities of being 1 and 0)
- used only once.

Otherwise, you are in deep trouble. If your bits aren't random, you can extract some information about the plaintext bits. If you reuse your key, you can XOR two ciphertexts to get the XOR of the plaintext, or, if by chance someone gets you to post a message with a plaintext known to him, he can extract the key (they actually did that for ENIGMA in WW2, so that's not unrealistic!). If the key is shorter than the message, you can employ statistics - say they key is 10 bytes long, you can divide the ciphertext into 10 parts which are all encoded with the same byte, and employ frequency analysis ... just to name a few attacks.

Comment: Can you provide a real working example on how you discover key from an XOR encrypted string?

Comment: +1 just for mentioning malleability of the OTP. Otherwise it is too frequently overlooked that the OTP only gives perfect secrecy, but no integrity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it so rarely gets mentioned but the one time pad (OTP) has one major short-coming which is avoided by using the likes of RSA. Imagine that it is known that you will send one of two messages regarding stock ABC to your broker based on some news you will get at 2:00pm. You will either send BUY or SELL. With OTP, it doesn't take much crypto-analysis to figure out what you sent, because the length alone gives it away.

IMHO, it's better to use something that changes the length when converting to ciphertext as most common encryption systems do.